# VSTS - Naming .Zip Files

Tags: azure-devops

I have a VSTS Build Pipeline. In this pipeline, I build an executable file. I want to create a .zip file from the executable file. In an attempt to do this, I've added an "Archive Files" task. In this task, I've set the "Archive file to create" property to: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyApp-$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth).zip`. This task successfully completes.

When I look in the output window, I see

```
Creating archive: D:\a\1\a\MyApp-$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth).zip
```

Basically, it looks like the task is replacing the directory at runtime but not the file name. I was expecting to see

```
Creating archive: D:\a\1\a\MyApp-2018.09.09.zip
```

This is creating a problem for me because, I want to use this file in the next task. However, the task can't seem to find it and I believe it's because of what's explained here.

In VSTS, how do I create a zip file and give it a name representative of the day?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct syntax for the date? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=vsts&tabs=yaml you should be using `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(Year:yyyy)`, `$(Month)`, and `$(DayOfMonth)` are not valid [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts).

Although they may work in the build number format section, they do not work elsewhere. The same goes for `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)`.

There should be no reason to append a date to the artifacts generated by your build, especially since you can have multiple builds on the same day, which in the example you provided will cause a name collision anyway.